# Enqueue styles and scripts incorrectly

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm making a custom plugin for WordPress.

I'm calling scripts and styles to the plugin, but it shows this error https://prnt.sc/10t0gl1
Can you please let me know how can I fix the code?
I have another WP v5.3 site and this works just fine, not sure why the error appears on WP v5.6

Here is my code in the plugin main PHP file:

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: DL Project Manager
 * Plugin URI: http://www.test.com
 * Description: This is the starter project management plugin.
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Luan Tran
 * Author URI: http://www.luantran.com
 * License: GPLv2 or later
 */

// Abort if this file is accessed directly.
if (!defined("ABSPATH")) {
    exit;
}

//define("PLUGIN_PATH", dirname(__FILE__));
define("PLUGIN_PATH", plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));
define("PLUGIN_URL", plugin_dir_url(__FILE__));

class DLProjectManager
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->addScripts();
        $this->addStyles();
    }

    //create DB tables
    public static function createDBTables()
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $tables = [
            $wpdb->prefix . 'dlpm_projects',
            $wpdb->prefix . 'dlpm_activities',
            $wpdb->prefix . 'dlpm_revenues',
        ];
        $charset = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
        $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
        $sql = "         
            CREATE TABLE $tables[0] (
                id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                project_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                description text NULL,
                budget DECIMAL NOT NULL,
                invoice_file_path text NULL,
                created_at datetime NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (id)
            )
            $charset_collate;
            
            CREATE TABLE $tables[1] (
                id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                project_id int NOT NULL,
                type varchar(20) NOT NULL,
                amount DECIMAL NOT NULL,
                description text NULL,
                invoice_file_path text NULL,
                created_at datetime NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (id),
                FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES $tables[0](id)
            )
            $charset_collate;

            CREATE TABLE $tables[2] (
                id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                project_id int NOT NULL,
                revenue decimal not null,
                PRIMARY KEY (id),
                FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES $tables[0](id)
            )
            $charset_collate;
        ";
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
        dbDelta($sql);
    }

    //add style & script
    function addStyles()
    {
        wp_enqueue_style('dl-custom-styles', PLUGIN_URL . "/assets/css/styles.css");
    }

    function addScripts()
    {
        wp_enqueue_script('dl-jquery-inputmask', PLUGIN_URL . "/assets/js/jquery.inputmask.js", array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('dl-custom-scripts', PLUGIN_URL . "/assets/js/scripts.js", array('jquery'));
    }

    //add menu
    function dlProjectManagerAdminAllMenu()
    {
        $this->dlProjectManagerAdminMenu();
        $this->dlProjectManagerAdminSubMenu();
    }

    function dlProjectManagerAdminMenu()
    {
        $page_title = 'Dashboard';
        $menu_title = 'DL Project Manager';
        $capability = 'manage_options';
        $menu_slug  = 'dl-project-manager';
        $function   = array($this, 'dashboardLayout');   //generate layout
        $icon_url   = 'dashicons-video-alt';   //menu icon
        $position   = 1;
        add_menu_page(
            $page_title,
            $menu_title,
            $capability,
            $menu_slug,
            $function,
            $icon_url,
            $position
        );
    }

    function dlProjectManagerAdminSubMenu()
    {
        $submenu_pages = [
            [
                'parent_slug' => 'dl-project-manager',
                'page_title' => 'Projects',
                'menu_title' => 'Projects',
                'capability' => 'manage_options',
                'menu_slug' => 'dl-project-manager-project-list',
                'function' => array($this, 'projectListLayout'),  //generate layout
                'position' => 2
            ], [
                'parent_slug' => 'dl-project-manager-project-list',
                'page_title' => 'New Project',
                'menu_title' => 'Add New Project',
                'capability' => 'manage_options',
                'menu_slug' => 'dl-project-manager-project-new',
                'function' => array($this, 'projectAddLayout'),  //generate layout
                'position' => 3
            ], [
                'parent_slug' => 'dl-project-manager-project-list',
                'page_title' => 'Edit Project',
                'menu_title' => 'Edit Project',
                'capability' => 'manage_options',
                'menu_slug' => 'dl-project-manager-project-edit',
                'function' => array($this, 'projectEditLayout'),  //generate layout
                'position' => 4
            ]
        ];

        foreach ($submenu_pages as $submenu_page) {
            add_submenu_page(
                $submenu_page['parent_slug'],
                $submenu_page['page_title'],
                $submenu_page['menu_title'],
                $submenu_page['capability'],
                $submenu_page['menu_slug'],
                $submenu_page['function']
            );
        }
    }


}



if (is_admin()) {
    $dlPM = new DLProjectManager();
    //add menu
    add_action('admin_menu', array($dlPM, 'dlProjectManagerAdminAllMenu'));
    //create tables in mysql when activating the plugin
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array($dlPM, 'createDBTables'));

    //add style & script
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($dlPM, 'addScripts'));
    add_action('wp_enqueue_styles', array($dlPM, 'addStyles'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your `__construct` method... You are calling the script and styles methods as soon as your class in instantiated.

Remove this:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->addScripts();
        $this->addStyles();
    }
```

or change to:

```
public function __construct() {}
```

or change to:

```
public function __construct() {
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'addScripts'));
    add_action('wp_enqueue_styles', array($this, 'addStyles'));
}
```

and remove them from your `if (is_admin())` check.

Comment: Yes, I already tried that but the custom css & script do not show anymore: https://prnt.sc/10t15zm